# jmeter - Looping based on DB query

Tags: jmeter

I need to tell my loop counter to loop x Times, based on the DB query.

[image]

My scenario is as follows

```
Execute the query
Count the lines
based on dynamic response from JDBC request, i need to place my looping logic
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a JMeter Variable in the "Variable Names" field of the [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request), i.e. put `url` there:

[image]

This way you will get the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

[image]

So you will be able to use `${url_#}` as the reference to the number of the matching rows in the Loop Controller.

More information: [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter)

P.S. It might be easier to use [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)