# jmeter - Looping based on DB query - use db data as variables

Tags: jmeter

Based on this thread: [jmeter - Looping based on DB query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61998179/jmeter-looping-based-on-db-query/62006152#62006152), i managed to get counter to the Loop controller, and and working fine.

Now i need updated version, where DB query returns 2 variables, so i can use them as parameters for the call.

[image]

```
url secret
https://test1.com/  1234
https://test2.com/  1234
https://test3.com/  1234
```

And to be able to use them in:

[image]

As:

[image]

But, when i tried to use them as: ${url_#}, ${key_#} test is not working.

Is there other any way how can i use those 2 variables fetched from DB query, and the looping logic to be respected?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following test elements combination:

- `${__jm__Loop Controller__idx}` pre-defined variable to get the current [Loop Controller's](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) iteration number
- [__intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) to add 1 to the iteration number (it's zero-based)
- [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) to put everything together

The combination would be:

```
${__V(url_${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)},)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. what help me was: `${__V(url_${__counter(,)})}` variable together with counter function.